# Mapping dict (from rdd) to recursively change column names in Python/PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with new variable name(col2) and old variable name(col1).

[image]

I have another dataframe (tf) with columns (named as in col1)

[image]

Desired result (tf_new) is to convert the column names into names in col2 (abs->fc_abc)

[image]

I have tried to avoid udf uptil now by doing the below:

```
#converting df into rdd
newrdd = df.rdd
#generating a map
keypair_rdd = newrdd.map(lambda x : (x[1],x[0]))
#creating key value pair
dict = keypair_rdd.collectAsMap()
```

Need help with using the dict to transform tf into tf_new.

Similar solution in Python would also be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Collect the first dataframe into a Python dictionary

```python
dict = df.agg(F.map_from_arrays(F.collect_list("col1"), 
  F.collect_list("col2"))).first()[0]
```

2. Create a list of all columns of `tf` and rename those columns that are contained in `dict`

```python
renamed_cols = [F.col(c).alias(dict[c]) if c in dict 
  else F.col(c) for c in tf.columns]
```

3. Use the renamed columns to the select the data

```python
tf.select(renamed_cols).show()
```